# Uploading large file using ng-file-upload and handling it to server side using hapijs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hapi.js, ng-file-upload

I have hapi js server at backend. I am uploading file using ng-file-upload. When I handled the file at hapi server it thrown an error:

> "TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'content-length' of
>   undefined"

My code is:

```
config: {
    validate: {
        payload: {
            file: Joi.object().required(),
            maxBytes: 209715200,
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true
        }
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        let form = new multiparty.Form();
        //console.dir(request.payload);
        form.parse(request.payload, function(err, fields, files) {
            if (err) return reply(err);
            else upload(files, reply);
         });
     }
}
```

My client side code is (ng-file-upload)

```
Upload.http({
    url: '/upload',
    data: file
});
```

Could anyone please help me? what is the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: What about file with small size. Is that OK?

Comment: did you fix this? i am getting the same error.